# Why does bool(val) prefer double implicit conversions over val.operator bool()?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion

The piece of code below dereferences a `nullptr`.

```
struct Foo {
    int *bar;
    operator int&() {
        return *bar;
    }
    explicit operator bool() const {
        return bar;
    }
};
int main() {
    Foo f {nullptr};
    auto _ = bool(f); 
}
```

1. Why does `bool(f)` call `bool(f.operator int&())` and not `f.operator bool()` as was intended?
2. Is there a way to make `bool(f)` call `f.operator bool()` as intended *without* marking `operator int&` as `explicit`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Argument conversion ranking takes precedence over return type conversion ranking in overload resolution for user-defined conversions

<sub>*All standard references below refers to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

#### Preparations

To avoid having to deal with segfaults, `auto` type deduction and consideration of `explicit` marked conversion functions, consider the following simplified variation of your example, which shows the same behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int bar{42};
    operator int&() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
        return bar;
    }
    operator bool() const {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo f {};
    // (A):
    bool a = f;  // Foo::operator int&()
}
```

---

#### TLDR

> Why does `bool(f)` call `bool(f.operator int&())` and not `f.operator bool()` as was intended?

The viable candidate functions to the initialization conversion sequence are

```
operator int&(Foo&)     
operator bool(const Foo&)
```

and [[over.match.best]/1.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.best#1.3), ranking on function arguments, takes precedence over [[over.match.best]/1.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.best#1.4), ranking on conversion from return type, meaning `operator int&(Foo&)` will be chosen as it is a non-ambiguous perfect match, for an argument of type `Foo&`, by the [over.match.best]/1.3 rule, whereas `operator bool(const Foo&)` is not.

In this regard, as we are relying on [over.match.best]/1.3, it is no different than simply overloading solely on `const`-qualification:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {};

void f(Foo&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
void f(const Foo&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }

int main() {
    Foo f1 {};
    const Foo f2{};
    f(f1); // void f(Foo&)
    f(f2); // void f(const Foo&)
}
```

> Is there a way to make `bool(f)` call `f.operator bool()` as intended without marking `operator int&` as explicit?

As per above, if you provide matching cv-qualifiers for the member function overloads, there can no longer be any differentiation on the implicit object argument as per [over.match.best]/1.3, and the `bool` conversion function will be chosen as most viable as per [over.match.best]/1.4. Note that by marking the `int&` conversion functions as `explicit`, it will no longer be a *viable* candidate, and the choice for the `bool` conversion function will not be due to it being the *most* viable overload, but by it being the *only* viable overload.

---

#### Details

The expression at (A) is initialization, with semantics governed specifically by [[dcl.init]/17.7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17.7) [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> **[dcl.init]/17** The semantics of initializers are as follows. The destination
> type is the type of the object or reference being initialized and the
> source type is the type of the initializer expression.
>
> - [...]
> - **/17.7** Otherwise, **if the source type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type, conversion functions are considered**. The applicable
>   conversion functions are enumerated ([over.match.conv]), and the best
>   one is chosen through overload resolution. The user-defined conversion
>   so selected is called to convert the initializer expression into the
>   object being initialized. [...]

where [[over.match.conv]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.conv#1) describes which conversion functions that are considered *candidate functions* in overload resolution:

> **[over.match.conv]/1** Under the conditions specified in [dcl.init], as part of an initialization of an **object of non-class type**, a conversion function can be invoked to **convert an initializer expression of class type to the type of the object being initialized**. Overload resolution is used to select the conversion function to be invoked. Assuming that “cv1 `T`” is the type of the object being initialized, and “cv `S`” is the type of the initializer expression, with `S` a class type, the candidate functions are selected as follows:
>
> - **/1.1** The conversion functions of `S` and its base classes are considered. Those non-explicit conversion functions that are not
>   hidden within `S` and yield type `T` or **a type that can be converted
>   to type `T` via a standard conversion sequence** are candidate
>   functions. [...] Conversion functions that return “reference to cv2
>   `X`” return lvalues or xvalues, depending on the type of reference, of
>   type “cv2 `X`” **and are therefore considered to yield `X` for this
>   process of selecting candidate functions.**

In this example, *cv* `T`, the type of the object being initialized, is `bool`, and thus both used-defined conversion functions are *viable* candidates, as one directly yields type `bool` and the other yields a type that can be converted to type `bool` via a standard conversion sequence (`int` to `bool`); as per [[conv.bool]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.bool):

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. [...]

Moreover, the type of the initializer expression is `Foo`, and [[over.match.funcs]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.funcs#4) governs that the cv-qualification of the type of the implicit object **parameter** for user-defined conversion functions is that of the cv-qualification of the respective function:

> For non-static member functions, the type of the implicit object
> parameter is
>
> - “lvalue reference to cv `X`” for functions **declared without a ref-qualifier** or with the & ref-qualifier
> - [...]
>
> where `X` is the class of which the function is a member and *cv* is
> the cv-qualification on **the member function declaration**. [...] For
> conversion functions, the function is considered to be a member of the
> class of the implied object argument for the purpose of defining the
> type of the implicit object parameter. [...]

Thus, w.r.t. overload resolution we may summarize as follows:

```
// Target type: bool
// Source type: Foo

// Viable candidate functions:
operator int&(Foo&)     
operator bool(const Foo&)
```

where we have added the implied object parameter as explicit function parameter, without loss of generality (as per [[over.match.funcs]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.funcs#5)), when continuing for how overload resolution picks the *best viable candidate*.

Now, [[over.ics.user]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.user), particularly [[over.ics.user]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.user#2) summarizes this:

> **[over.ics.user]/2** [...] Since **an implicit conversion sequence is an initialization**, the **special rules for initialization by user-defined conversion apply** when selecting the best user-defined conversion for a user-defined conversion sequence (see [over.match.best] and [over.best.ics]).

particularly that the rules for selecting the *best viable candidate* is governed by [[over.match.best]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.best), particularly [[over.match.best]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.best#1):

> **[over.match.best]/1** [...] Given these definitions, a viable function `F1` is defined to be a better function than another viable function `F2` if for all arguments `i`, `ICSi(F1)` is not a worse conversion sequence than `ICSi(F2)`, and then
>
> - **/1.3** for some argument `j`, `ICSj(F1)` is a better conversion sequence than `ICSj(F2)`, or, **if not that**,
> - **/1.4** the context **is an initialization by user-defined conversion** (see [dcl.init], [over.match.conv], and [over.match.ref])
>   and the standard conversion sequence **from the return type of `F1` to
>   the destination type** (i.e., the type of the entity being
>   initialized) **is a better conversion sequence** than the standard
>   conversion sequence from the return type of `F2` to the destination
>   type

The key here is that [over.match.best]/1.4, regarding conversion on the return type of the candidate (to the target type) *only applies* if the overloads cannot be disambiguated by means of [over.match.best]/1.3. In our example, however, recall that the viable candidate functions are:

```
operator int&(Foo&)     
operator bool(const Foo&)
```

As per [[over.ics.rank]/3.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.rank#3.2), particularly [[over.ics.rank]/3.2.6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.rank#3.2.6):

> **[over.ics.rank]/3** Two implicit conversion sequences of the same form are indistinguishable conversion sequences unless one of the
> following rules applies:
>
> - [...]
> - **/3.2** Standard conversion sequence `S1` is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence `S2` if
>
>   - [...]
>   - **/3.2.6** `S1` and `S2` are reference bindings ([dcl.init.ref]), and the types to which the references refer are  **the same type
>     except for top-level cv-qualifiers**, and the type to which the
>     reference initialized by `S2` refers **is more cv-qualified** than the
>     type to which the reference initialized by `S1` refers.

meaning, that for an argument of type `Foo&`, `operator int&(Foo&)` will be a better (/1.3: exact) match, whereas for e.g. an argument of type `const Foo&`, `operator bool(const Foo&)` will the only match (`Foo&` will not be viable).